# Get currently active ROS 2 distros programatically

Tags: ros, ros2, packaging

Is there a way to get a list of currently active ROS 2 distros, that a package needs to support?
This would be good for CI jobs. We could then warn the maintainers if their package is not supporting the required distros, and also when tests again EOL distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might what you are looking for?

https://discourse.ros.org/t/snapshots-for-iron/31878/2